# Error in java with TextFieldHandler and ButtonHandler

Tags: java

When i compile my code i get these 2 errors:
1)LabelFrame.TextFieldHandler is not abstract and does not override abstract method actionPerformed(ActionEvent) in ActionListener
2)method does not override or implement a method from a supertype @Override

The same errors apply for the ButtonHandler class.
Can you please explain my mistake and how can I fix it?
Thank you in advance!

This is my code:

```
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import java.util.*;

public class LabelFrame extends JFrame {
    private final JTextField url;
    private final JButton backButton;
    private final JButton loadButton;
    private Stack urlStack = new Stack();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LabelFrame frame = new LabelFrame();
        frame.show();
    }


    public LabelFrame() {
        super("WebStalker");
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        url = new JTextField(30);
        add(url);
        loadButton = new JButton("Load");
        add(loadButton);
        backButton = new JButton("Back");
        add(backButton);

        TextFieldHandler tHandler = new TextFieldHandler();
        ButtonHandler bHandler = new ButtonHandler();
        url.addActionListener(tHandler);
        backButton.addActionListener(bHandler);
        loadButton.addActionListener(bHandler);
   }

    private class TextFieldHandler implements ActionListener {
        @Override
        public void actionPerfomed(ActionEvent event) {
             String urlString = "";
             urlString = event.getActionCommand();
        }
     }

     private class ButtonHandler implements ActionListener {
        @Override
         public void actionPerfomed(ActionEvent event) {
             if (event.getSource() == loadButton) {
                 try {
                     //remember url for back button
                     urlStack.push(url.getText());
                 } catch (Exception e) {
                     System.out.println("Unable to load page");
                 }
             } else if (event.getSource() == backButton) {
                 if (urlStack.size() <= 1) {
                     return;
                 }
                 try {
                     urlStack.pop();
                     String urlString = (String)urlStack.peek();
                 } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println("Unable to load page");
                 }
             }
         }
     }
}
```

Comment: what is the java version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the spelling:

Your code:

```
private class TextFieldHandler implements ActionListener {
    @Override
    public void actionPerfomed(ActionEvent event) {
        //Your code
    }
}
```

and it should be :

```
private class TextFieldHandler implements ActionListener {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
        //Your code
    }
}
```

You spelled it `actionPerfomed` instead of `actionPerformed`. That should solve it

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in your overridden method names in the `TextFieldHandler` and `ButtonHandler` classes

update method name from `actionPerfomed` to `actionPerformed`